# How to delete entire row when cell contains specific value but NOT effect row 1

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, macros, row

I need to delete all rows (entire row) that contains a 0 or positive value in Column N.  The code below does this properly but the issue is that row 1 has column headers (all text).  This row gets deleted by my current macro.  I need this row to not be included in the range the macro effects or locked somehow.  The number of rows is dynamic and thus I cannot specify a fixed range for the macro to run on.

```
 Sub Step20()


 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Dim i As Long
 For i = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If (Range("N" & i).Value >= 0) Then
       Range("N" & i).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
 Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Thanks !

Comment: Change the `to 1` in your for loop to `to 2`. Then it will never look at row 1

Comment: @ScottCraner ahh! So obvious -- That worked perfectly.  If you would like to submit that as an answer I will mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your code to run from the last row until first row, which is the entire document. What if you change to run just until row 2? You would only need to make sure your headers are in row 1!

Here's what I would change in your code:

```
For i = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
```

This way you preserve the first row and still get your job done.